# Where does the code following an await run

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

If you have some code like this:

```
var result = await task;
mycode(result);
```

- Will mycode always run synchronously if the task already completed?
- In case the task has not yet completed, in what cases does mycode not execute synchronously with completion?
  (SynchronizationContext not null on await and different on complete would be one)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I explain the [details of `await` semantics](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) on my blog.

> Will mycode always run synchronously if the task already completed?

Yes. The `await` operator first checks to see if the task has already completed; if it has, then it continues executing synchronously.

If the task has not already completed, then `await` will create a task continuation to resume executing the current method when the task has completed. When `await` does this, by default it will capture the current "context" and resume the method on that context. This "context" is `SynchronizationContext.Current`, unless it is `null`, in which case it is `TaskScheduler.Current`.

> In case the task has not yet completed, in what cases does mycode not execute synchronously with completion? (SynchronizationContext not null on await and different on complete would be one)

[`await` always schedules its continuations with the `ExecuteSynchronously` flag](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/12/dont-block-in-asynchronous-code.html) (this is an undocumented implementation detail described on my blog). However, [there's some situations where `ExecuteSynchronously` doesn't execute synchronously](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/02/07/10265067.aspx), most notably if there was a `TaskScheduler` captured by `await` that determines it isn't compatible with the completing thread - but there are also other situations, like if the completing thread has been aborted, or if there's too much stack used.

Even if it *does* execute synchronously, as you noted, if there was a `SynchronizationContext` captured by `await`, it will decide whether or not it's compatible with the current context, and only *actually* execute synchronously if this check passes.

In short, you can't *assume* it'll always execute synchronously.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! I also learn from this I should not go to the effort of rewriting my code to use ContinueWith with ExecuteSynchronously. If I make sure I have no SynchronizationContext and the TaskScheduler allows it, I can probably assume the code will run synchronously. The article you reference mentions 2200 frames, so if I only have a donzen or so, that should be fine.

Comment: @TomDeseyn: I'm still wondering why you *need* to ensure it'll run synchronously. What's your actual use case?

Comment: Good question! Data is coming from an async read loop. To track the data changes you can subscribe to an event. The event generator is unaware of the subscriber(s). So to get the latest state, you also need to perform a get operation. The events are emitted from the read loop. The get operation is completed from the read loop. When the get operation completes, you want to check synchronously with the read loop whether an event has already occurred otherwise the get may overwrite an event.

Comment: @TomDeseyn: Speaking honestly, depending on synchronous continuations makes me nervous. It just seems like one of those things that will only fail in obscure, heavy-usage cases only seen in production. If there's any way of modifying the design so that the code doesn't care whether the continuations are synchronous, I'd do that instead.

Comment: I agree with you. I intend to open source part of the code I am writing. Maybe I'll make an issue on the repo so we can have a design discussion :) I think .NET should provide a ForceExecuteSynchronously flag which throws if it cannot fulfill the request. Should be made available as a ConfigureAwait option.

Answer (score 1):

> Will mycode always run synchronously if the task already completed?

Yes, it does.

> In case the task has not yet completed, in what cases does mycode not execute synchronously with completion?

If the task is not completed then it's quite possible that the code follows `await` would be executed by another thread of the thread pool. Actually what compiler does when sees async/await is to create a state machine and using continuations it states how the code would be executed. At the runtime, when CLR notes that the task has not completed, pauses the execution of the code at this point and releases the thread on which the code was running. Later, when the task would be completed, the CLR get's another thread or the same thread to continue the execution of the code.

Comment: I know it is common for the code before and after await to be executed on different threads. My question is about the code after the await being executed on a different thread than the **completion** thread.

Comment: @TomDeseyn Provided that there isn't any other await call, then the code after the await would run on the completion thread.

Comment: Can you update your answer and give one or two examples where the code does not run on the completion thread (e.g. the 'other await' could be one of them)?